# Why does JHipster page not accept String for ZonedDateTime

Tags: jhipster, zoneddatetime

I recently changed my domain objects from LocalDate to ZonedDateTime. I also created a brand new play JHipster application and one play entity choosing ZonedDateTime for two class members. The test application (new) works while my existing application does not, even after going through all the code twice. I loaded CSV data using Liquibase and my listing code shows the dates properly. Here's what the data looks like in my Maven output, e.g.  entrydate='2017-02-23T19:53:18-05:00[America/New_York]', transaction='Initial Balance',

When I choose to update the date-time value with the "datetime-picker" in the dialog.html, a string date time is shown in the text box but when I push "Save" I get an "Internal Server Error" and the Maven output shows:

.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Text '2017-02-    26T00:53:18.000Z' could not be parsed at index 23 (through reference chain: org.ciwise.blackhole.domain.GenLedger["entrydate"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '2017-02-26T00:53:18.000Z' could not be parsed at index 23 (through reference chain: org.ciwise.blackhole.domain.GenLedger["entrydate"])]

Does anyone have an idea why the picker would produce String text in the text box that isn't acceptable when the HTTP PUT occurs (edit)?

My application does use Service classes but they handle the same Java domain objects as the JPA Repository classes do.

One more thing, the schema for the API shows e.g. "entrydate": "2017-02-23T21:44:04.859Z", but the actual JSON return is "entrydate": "2017-02-23T19:53:18.000-0500",

I'm hoping someone else has encountered this before.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

The answer here was to re-introduce application.yml. Inside this file it defines some Spring profiles but of most importance, it provides an option for Jackson serialization into JSON e.g.

jackson:
        serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps: false

This resolved my issue.